# How webpage content blocking works even after removing javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

If you had ever used sites like quora or wsj you might have noticed that their content appears at the background, then black layer above it and then some kind of message screen.

The reason for doing this is that owner's don't want to show content to any person who is not logged in or something similar. I successfully tried to escape this blocking of many small sites by going into google's developer tool and deleting specific code blocks which stops from content being visible.

I am trying something similar on quora but not able to remove the light black screen layer. I removed all the external javascript files and related codes ; then also this black screen stays as it is. How does it works ? If not javascript then is their anything else who has such a power to make screen block.

Example Images from quora :

(1) blocked content then black layer then message

[image]

(2) Chrome's developer tool trying to inspect the code

[image]

(3) Removed message screen but black screen stays
[image]

Comment: again right click and inspect. then see what it gets.

Comment: Just remove the div with the id `__w2_SOMETHING_signup_wall_wrapper`. This should do it. To scroll, use the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some overlay layer and **pointer-events** are set to **none** on the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the element with the class `vertical_alignment_wrapper`